# Android App crashes when I try to send a text

Tags: java, android, text, sms, smsmanager

After some research it appears that the crash is a result of novice coding, more specifically maybe the location of where the sending sms function occurs The app only crashes when I try to send a text through this app. It crashes with a virtual phone and an actual phone connected via usb in Developer mode. Sim card is fine. I have no idea how to fix the crash. Thanks for the help! Here is the code from MainActivity.java below. I do have a MessageReceiver class which works fine.

```java
//import stuff is fine
...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText UserNumber;    //tvNumber
    EditText TrapID;        //tvMessage
    IntentFilter intentFilter;

    private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //where to put received message
            //putting in text view for now to demonstrate it works
            TextView inTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
            inTxt.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("message"));
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //intent to filter for SMS received
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

        Button SimulateActive = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SimulateActive);
        SimulateActive.setOnClickListener(sendAutoMsg);
    };

    private View.OnClickListener sendAutoMsg = new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            String trapID = TrapID.getText().toString();
            String AutoMessage = ("Hello. Trap:"+trapID+"has been activated.");
            String usrnum = UserNumber.getText().toString();
            sendMsg (usrnum, AutoMessage);
        }
    };

    protected void sendMsg (String usrnum, String AutoMessage){
        String SENT = "Message Sent";
        String DELIVERED = "Message Delivered";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT),0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED),0);

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(usrnum, null, AutoMessage, sentPI, deliveredPI);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        //register the receiver
        registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        //unregister receiver
        unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }


}//end
```

Comment: Please add crash logs

Answer (score 0):

Create two `EditText` in layout file (eg: `number` and `trap`) and point `UserNumber` and `TrapID` like below in onCreate(),

```
UserNumber =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
TrapID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.trap);
```

give SEND_SMS permission in android manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Check if you need to give runtime permission in onCreate() as well (Depends on your `targetSdkVersion`),

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
```

adding all these, code worked for me. Hope this helps.